# python- swap letters between 2 strings

Tags: python, string, function

I need help with an exe (python)

Given strings input1 and input2, return a single string with input1 and
 input2 separated by a space ' ',
 except swap the first 2 chars of each string.
 e.g.
   'mix', pod' -> 'pox mid

Comment: using a function

Comment: What, exactly, do you need help with? What does your function look like, and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(input1,input2):    
    return input2[:2]+input1[2:]+' '+input1[:2]+input2[2:]
```

Comment: It isn't advisable to provide a full answer when the OP hasn't really shown their own attempt. this answer works fine, though

Comment: Ypu are right. Fixed. Anyway this guy is probably just trying to get his homework done easily, so maybe I should have kept the bug there :D.